# How to increase Alt + Left (go to previous page in Chrome browsing history) from the upper limit of 50?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11, history, browsing, alt

In Chrome, you can go to a previous page in your browsing history using Alt+Left. It seems that the upper limit on the number of pages Chrome remembers is 50. (Windows 11, desktop PC)
I would need to increase that number to at least 200.

Is this possible?

I cannot find this number in settings and cannot find anything about this topic on the net.
Either nobody had this problem before or I don't know how to phrase the question properly (English is my second language so that's always an option).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could post a feature request on the Chrome forums.